# Get the smaller and bigger array in Kotlin style

Tags: kotlin

There are two byte arrays, and I want to compare them byte by byte, and find the smaller one and the bigger one.

Kotlin code:

```
val array1 = byteArrayOf(1,2,4, ...)
val array2 = byteArrayOf(1,2,3, ...)

val (smaller, bigger) = array1.zip(array2)
    .dropWhile { it.first == it.second }
    .firstOrNull()?.let {
        when (it.first < it.second) {
            true -> array1 to array2
            else -> array2 to array1
        }
    } ?: array1 to array2
```

I wonder if there is any other simpler way to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly simpler:

```
var (smaller, bigger) = array1.zip(array2)
    .find { it.first != it.second }
    .let {
        when (it == null || it.first < it.second) {
            true -> array1 to array2
            false -> array2 to array1
        }
    }
```